# Decrypt encrypted key using Certificate not working in .NET but works in Openssql

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, rsa

So for several weeks I have been trying to figure out why I can't decrypt the encrypted key element from a soap response.   I took another route just to see if I can even decrypt the encrypted key element with other means.  In this case I used openssl and I was able to get it working.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" enc -base64 -d -in encryptedKeyElement.txt > result.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" rsautl -decrypt -inkey myPrivateKey.pem -in encryptedKeyElement.txt -oaep -out decryptedkey.txt
```

With the decrypted key I was then able to decrypt the soap body element.

Now the question is what does this not work in .NET?

```
var encryptedKey = "AnQtlNmAapLaX862hobD/p/RaPStJ+ygqrJMN9LM6i1548auXJ5wk0SVeQTdiOVMe3wv9lhkXKAZD6u6rOUCa3es+xyHrdRBplg0mJBfkprz84AWcI36TsoOhmntLZF9Yr+ZMyYzOCfzK7T0b1rTYh2X2Wjbg8xu/KGuNic9HmF9l5fk4y2mQeM8C3ST+HACPDSrvhodAmucj9X0sWPA/v0Y116mevpWvUsekc6iMuAhfBfP2UaVO9HZofvk3WDP0LdBWOdOoifop5Sbz+QT3dt0u2u96Oi3wRLagXv56sHVvHsiNGuHyEhzRKF8rAhnjh4VQSruuDrM/PfaH4OgHg=="
var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\eSar\certificates\xxxxxx.pfx", "xxxxx");
var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)clientCert.PrivateKey;
byte[] key = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedKey), false);
```

Error I get:

> The parameter is incorrect. {**EDITED**.  I put the wrong error message. Sorry]

Stack Trace

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 503
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 458
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 126
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
```

Comment: Looks to me like it is talking about being unable to get your private key from the certificate.

Comment: I get a private key in the variable rsa.  I even check clientCert.HasPrivateKey boolean value.  Its true.

Comment: The only thing is different is the oaep.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Doesn't oeap require that the second argument to `Decrypt` be `true`?

Comment: I don't see it on the website. So are you saying its not being used?

Comment: You passed `-oaep` to OpenSSL, so you need to pass `true` as the second parameter to that particular Decrypt overload.

Comment: @bartonjs.  I get this error  now "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding"